# Bazaar checkout logging

Tags: logging, bazaar

Is there any checkout history logging in bazaar or is there a way to turn it on, or monitor checkouts on the server?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search yields this command: (http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-guide/browsing_history.html)

```
% bzr log -r 1000..          # Revision 1000 and everything after it
% bzr log -r ..1000          # Everything up to and including r1000
% bzr log -r 1000..1100      # changes from 1000 to 1100
% bzr log -r 1000            # The changes in only revision 1000
```

There are also graphical tools available such as `QBzr` and `bzr-gtk`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: not exactly the bzr log command shows check in history but not checkout from what i recall

Comment: I'm not sure whether that exists out of the box - maybe you could code up a filter that checks your servers connection logs for checkouts? What do you want to use it for?

Comment: it is really to check to see who is checking stuff out and what they are checking out